# Why do I get this error when trying to map on a list of lists?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use `map` to write a function that takes the last elements of a list of lists. For example:

```
 [ [0,0,4],[2,4,2],[1,3,5],[3,1,1] ] => [4,2,5,1]
```

I've written this:

```
 func l = map (last l)
```

and got this error:

```
    > ERROR - Type error in application
 Expression     : func [[0,0,4],[2,4,2],[1,3,5],[3,1,1]]
 Term           : [[0,0,4],[2,4,2],[1,3,5],[3,1,1]]
 Type           : [[c]]
 Does not match : [a -> b]
```

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're doing the wrong thing with `last`. What you are trying to do is apply it to each inner list inside the outer list `l`. What you're actually doing is applying it to the outer list `l` itself, and then `map` makes no sense.

You need to write `map last l` instead.

You can see the right form of the arguments to `map` from its type:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

This means that `map` takes two arguments, one of type `a -> b` and another of type `[a]`.

Note that in your code you're only giving it the first argument (`last l`). This is a valid thing to do in Haskell in general (look up "partial application" or "currying"), but here the first argument is supposed to be a function and `last l` certainly isn't.

In this case your list `l` is the thing of type `[a]`, so `a` = `[Integer]` (ignoring numeric overloading). The first argument should be a function of type `[Integer] -> b`, and you want to use `last` which means that `b` = `Integer`. So the end result will be of type `[Integer]` as wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
func l = map last l
```

no parenthesis.

If you take a look at the types in `func [[0,0,4],[2,4,2],[1,3,5],[3,1,1]` call you'll notice that since `l = [[0,0,4],[2,4,2],[1,3,5],[3,1,1]]`, the type of l is `[[c]]` but then type of `last l` is  `[c]` while map expects `[a -> b]` as it's first argument.

Comment: It *would* try to map the result over whatever you apply `func l` to, but the type error from trying to pass `last l` as the first argument to `map` keeps it from ever getting to that point.

Comment: yes, that's because haskell is trying to figure out the types from the function definition and the particular application and they don't check.

Answer (score 1):

Or even by using point free notation:
`f = map last`

Which, in ghci, yields the type:

```
GHCI> let f = map last
GHCI> :t f
f :: [[b]] -> [b]
GHCI> f [ [0,0,4],[2,4,2],[1,3,5],[3,1,1] ]
[4,2,5,1]
```